# Hibernate 3.6 mapping exception after upgrading to Spring 4.3.x

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have been required to upgrade Spring from 3.x so now it's at 4.3. Hoping not to require upgrade on Hibernate 3.6 as well. The Spring upgrade docs indicate that though they've deprecated 3.6 that it will not be entirely removed yet.

This is the error with hibernate mapping:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.***.GenericEnumUserType, at table: transactions, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(transaction_type)]
```

I've been using the FlexibleSolution option here for my customer usertype: https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/Java5EnumUserType

Here is what the exception is complaining about in the hibernate mapping:

```
<property name="transactionType" column="transaction_type" not-null='true' length="1" lazy='false'>
      <type name="com.***.GenericEnumUserType">
        <param name="enumClass">com.***.ChargeTransactionType</param>
      </type>
    </property>
```

I've been trying to understand why it is failing now but I haven't been able to come to a conclusion. There has been no issue until the Spring upgrade. Does anybody know why or have a solution?

Comment: Though it's deprecated but still highly recommended to go with Hibernate 5.2, as while upgrading spring some hibernate dependencies () also got updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like my problem was Java 7. Dependency was pulling in transitive dependency on Java 7 while the original package was using Java 8. This was causing some issues in resolving the Spring and hibernate dependencies... it was all solved once we noticed this and pushed the dependency to also use Java 8.